# Sci-fi movie about auras and spirituality from the 80's or maybe 70's

Tags: story-identification, movie

Several years back I caught what I believe to be the end of a sci-fi movie on tv. It really captivated me but I was running late and had to go before I could figure out the name.

The movie seemed to be based around a main character who was in the process of being apprenticed or trained how to perceive or read energies and auras around him and in other people. There were bad guys too, they seemed to mix and mingle with the good guys.

The part of the movie I caught was taking place at a retreat or compound far from the civilized world(maybe the jungles of central or south America?).

Before I had to leave the main character and a girl, far more advanced in her craft than the main character, take a hike to an old ruin in the middle of the jungle. At this location the main character is confronted by one of the bad guys. The city becomes restored to it's former glory and then..... I had to leave for work.

The bad guy is a semi famous actor who may be of german or similar descent.

Does any of this sound familiar to anyone?

Comment: When you return, you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like **"The Celestine Prophecy"** an novel by James Redfield and 2006 movie directed by Armand Mastroianni.

Comment: I just looked it up. You were 100% correct. Thank you. The movie is a lot newer than I thought it was!

Comment: Great! It's a good read.
Please make the question as answered, Thanks